# Decrypt binary file with RSA_private_decrypt()

Tags: c, encryption, rsa, private-key

I'm currently a computer science student and I got an exercise that I can't solve.

I have to decrypt the file "cipheredkey.bin" with the function RSA_private_decrypt(). Therefore I've only got the private key "privkey.pem".

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>


EVP_PKEY* readEVPkey(const char* keyfile)
{
        EVP_PKEY *evp_key;
        FILE *fp;

        fp = fopen(keyfile, "rb");

        if (fp == NULL) {
                printf("Unable to open file %s\n", keyfile);
        } else {
                printf("Opened file %s\n", keyfile);
        }

        evp_key = PEM_read_PrivateKey(fp, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        if (evp_key == NULL) {
                printf("EVP_PKEY is NULL\n\n");
        } else {
                printf("EVP_PKEY not NULL\n\n");
        }

        fclose(fp);
        return evp_key;
}


int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
        int                     flen                    = NULL;
        int                     padding                 = RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING;
        const unsigned char     *decrypted_msg          = NULL;
        unsigned char           *encrypted_msg          = NULL;
        int                     decrypted_length        = NULL;

        char                    *err                    = NULL;

        EVP_PKEY                *evp                    = NULL;
        RSA                     *privkey                = NULL;




        evp = readEVPkey("privkey.pem");
        privkey = EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(evp);        // convert evp to rsa key

        flen = RSA_size(privkey);

        encrypted_msg = malloc(RSA_size(privkey));
        printf("size of encrypted_msg: %d\n", strlen(encrypted_msg));
        FILE *in = fopen("cipheredkey.bin", "r+");
        if (in == NULL) {
                printf("File cipheredkey.bin not found.\n");
        } else {
                fwrite(encrypted_msg,sizeof(*encrypted_msg), RSA_size(privkey), in);
                printf("encrypted_msg: %s\n", encrypted_msg);
        }

        decrypted_msg = malloc(sizeof(encrypted_msg));


        decrypted_length = RSA_private_decrypt(flen, decrypted_msg, encrypted_msg, privkey, padding);
        printf("1) decrypted_length: %i\n", decrypted_length);


        if (decrypted_length == -1) {
                ERR_load_crypto_strings();

                printf("FAIL: %s\n",ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(),NULL));

        } else {
                printf("1) decrypted_length: %i\n", decrypted_length);
                printf("Decrypted message: %s\n", decrypted_msg);
        }
}
```

> Output: FAIL: error:04099079:rsa
>   routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_OAEP_mgf1:oaep decoding error

There could be a problem with reading the binary file into char* or maybe there are some problems with the size of my variables.

This is the binary file "cipheredkey.bin". Read with cat

```
���;PۘU;PۘU;PۘUsJT3NOVG3GyH0hqTNShmAz8LLQChDvq2PyyaA/0SZTNJcYp15Mpyj0xHzF5wKz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```

Would be awesome to get some help from you

Comment: That's way too large to be a single RSA-OAEP encrypt. Furthermore, obviously the first bytes are mangled, as the rest seems base 64 encoded. That could mean that the file is corrupted or that the start of the file is encoded differently. My first thought is that the ciphertext is mangled though. Ask the supplier, you *should not* have to guess the first part of the file, probably a mistake was made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My prof gave me nearly the same task and I broke my head with your code today.

It seems that you swapped decrypted_msg and encrypted_msg;

So change

```
RSA_private_decrypt(flen, decrypted_msg, encrypted_msg, privkey, padding);
```

to

```
RSA_private_decrypt(flen, encrypted_msg, decrypted_msg, privkey, padding);
```

For me its now running, but the result is garbage. 
Hope its not too late and it helps.

Comment: Thank you. I realized that the file "cipheredkey.bin" was corrupted. This is also why youve got garbage as result.